UrlFetchApp.fetch() running into a timeout without any response
I have a list of domains in a Google sheet, trying to fetch title, description, H1 and H2 from a big list of domains and write it back to the sheet. 99% of the domains are running through smoothly with some header modifications, but at the following domains i am running into the strange timeout without any error:

accuweather.com
nasdaq.com
haberaybasti.com
militarycupid.com
wetter.de

for testing purpose - the following domains are working fine:

potv.bg
actualno.com
honeymoments.de
rosenheim24.de
mamaliefde.nl
i-diakopes.gr
liteapks.com
kreuzwortraetsellexikon.de

For me, it would be fine, if i could skip the domains and not it in the sheet, that there was an error or that the request timed out, but somehow i cannot get it working with try / catch, as i am getting no timeout message. Would appreciate every help.
please find enclosed my current code.
function fetchData(url) {
  var headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Priority': 'u=0, i',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"macOS"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-669d8ffa-6c30c4d90649d665390140a4'
  };
  var options = {
    'followRedirects': true,
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'headers': headers,
    'timeout': 10000 // Timeout set to 10 seconds
  };
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
    
    if (responseCode === 200) {
      var content = response.getContentText();
      
      var titleMatch = content.match(/<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/);
      var title = titleMatch && titleMatch[1] ? titleMatch[1] : "-";
      
      var metaDescriptionMatch = content.match(/<meta\s+name="description"\s+content="([^"]*)"/i);
      var metaDescription = metaDescriptionMatch && metaDescriptionMatch[1] ? metaDescriptionMatch[1] : "-";
      
      var h1Match = content.match(/<h1[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/h1>/i);
      var h1 = h1Match && h1Match[1] ? h1Match[1] : "-";
      
      var h2Match = content.match(/<h2[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/h2>/i);
      var h2 = h2Match && h2Match[1] ? h2Match[1] : "-";
      
      return {
        title: title,
        metaDescription: metaDescription,
        h1: h1,
        h2: h2,
        success: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        title: "Failed to fetch",
        metaDescription: "Failed to fetch",
        h1: "Failed to fetch",
        h2: "Failed to fetch",
        success: false
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error fetching URL: ' + url + ' - ' + e.message);
    return {
      title: 'DNS Error',
      metaDescription: 'DNS Error',
      h1: 'DNS Error',
      h2: 'DNS Error',
      success: false
    };
  }
}

function processUrlsIndividually() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETNAMEINTHERE");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("check_plmWebsites");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var lastFetchedIndex = getLastFetchedIndex(values);
  var startIndex = lastFetchedIndex + 1;

  Logger.log('Starting processing from index: ' + startIndex);

  for (var i = startIndex; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (isCloseToTimeout()) {
      Logger.log('Approaching timeout, stopping script execution.');
      break;
    }

    var url = values[i][0]; // Placement column (A)
    if (!url) continue; // Skip if URL is empty or undefined

    var urlData = fetchData(url);

    if (urlData.success) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9, 1, 4).setValues([[urlData.title, urlData.metaDescription, urlData.h1, urlData.h2]]); // Columns I, J, K, L
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 13).setValue(new Date()); // Column M (fetched)
      Logger.log('Successfully fetched URL: ' + url);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 13).setValue('Skipped due to timeout'); // Column M (fetched)
      Logger.log('Failed to fetch URL: ' + url + ' - Skipped due to timeout.');
    }

    // Sleep for 1 second between requests to avoid hitting rate limits
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }

  Logger.log('Processing completed up to index: ' + (i - 1));
}

function getLastFetchedIndex(values) {
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][12]) { // Column M (fetched)
      return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function isCloseToTimeout() {
  var runtime = new Date().getTime() - SCRIPT_START_TIME.getTime();
  return runtime > 5 * 60 * 1000; // Stop execution after 5 minutes to be safe
}

var SCRIPT_START_TIME = new Date();



About but at the following domains i am running into the strange timeout without any error, can you provide the sample URLs for testing?

sure. these are the domains not working:
accuweather.com
nasdaq.com
haberaybasti.com
militarycupid.com
wetter.de

these are some domains perfectly working: potv.bg
actualno.com
honeymoments.de
rosenheim24.de
mamaliefde.nl
i-diakopes.gr
liteapks.com
kreuzwortraetsellexikon.de

Thank you for replying. About For me, it would be fine, if i could skip the domains and not it in the sheet, that there was an error or that the request timed out, from your updated question, it seems that you have already known the invalid domains. In that case, how about skipping the URLs by checking the domain? For example, as a simple way, how about modifying if (!url) continue; to if (!url || ["accuweather.com","nasdaq.com","haberaybasti.com","militarycupid.com","wetter.de"].some(domain => url.includes(domain))) continue;? But, if I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

I would like to have kind of a timeout function, as the input list of urls is changing over time, as well as the list of url which cannot be fetched. The idea would be to simply set the status "timed out" in the col "lastFetch" if it takes longer than 10 seconds to fetch the domain, but somehow i cannot get it working, as i get no response / error message to trigger the time out. The scripts runs infinitely and then hard stops at 5 minutes as coded.

Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.
